# List only samples not containing a name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query samples so that it only displays a result if it has a name that does not contain 'CP'. So if there is a name of 'CP', don't show rows for that sample, however, if there is no 'CP' and has a name of 'Dirt' or 'Dust', show rows for that sample number.

Here is my attempt:

```
select distinct SampNum
from results
where (SampName = 'Dirt' or SampName = 'Dust')
  and SampName not in ('CP')
```

Raw Data:

```
SampNum | SampName
1         'Dirt'
1         'Dust'
1         'CP'
2         'Dirt'
2         'Dust'
3         'Dust'
4         'CP'
```

Expected Output:

```
SampNum                     
2               
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select SampNum
from results
group by SampNum
having sum(case when SampName in ('Dirt', 'Dust') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when SampName = 'CP' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot...

```
select distinct SampNum 
from results 
where (SampName = 'Dirt' or SampName = 'Dust') 
and SampNum not in (Select SampNum From results Where SampName in ('CP'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXCEPT` here, to return the SampNum's with Dirt or Dust - except those also having CP:

```
select SampNum
from results
where (SampName = 'Dirt' or SampName = 'Dust')
EXCEPT
select SampNum
from results
where SampName = 'CP'
```

dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bd2b69767319581d91fd5c484de2583

```
create table results (SampNum int, SampName varchar(10));
insert into results values (1,'Dirt');
insert into results values (1,'Dust');
insert into results values (1,'CP');
insert into results values (2,'Dirt');
insert into results values (2,'Dust');
insert into results values (3,'Dust');
insert into results values (4,'CP');

select SampNum
from results
where (SampName = 'Dirt' or SampName = 'Dust')
EXCEPT
select SampNum
from results
where SampName = 'CP';
```

Returns:

```
SampNum
      2
      3
```

Comment: from the raw data example, this query would still list SampNum 1, even though SampNum 1 has a 'CP'

Comment: @Brad, it does? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bd2b69767319581d91fd5c484de2583